# How change standard decoration in zend form

Tags: zend-framework

in my Directory Form i have FormArena

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'warrior',array(
            'decorators' => array(
                'ViewHelper',
            ),
            'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,
            'separator' => '', 
        ));
```

On my view page i have

```
 <?php echo $this->forms['formarena']->getItem('warrior'); ?>
```

And in controller i have

```
$getWarriorsList = $this->objArena->getActiveUsers($this->varUserData['id']);

        $objFormArena = new FormArena();
        if (!empty($getWarriorsList)){
            foreach($getWarriorsList AS $varWarriors)
                $varOptions[$varWarriors['id_users']] = $varWarriors['nick'];
            $objFormArena->warrior->addMultiOptions($varOptions);
            unset($varOptions); 
        }

       $this->view->forms = array(
            'formarena' => $objFormArena,
        );
```

Ok so it is easy. I take data from base and add option to view by controller. But when i see source code on page i have:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="warrior-27">
        <input type="radio" name="warrior" id="warrior-27" value="27">makapaka</label>
    <label for="warrior-29">
        <input type="radio" name="warrior" id="warrior-29" value="29">Kasia</label>
</div>
```

but i need do

```
<div class="radio">
    <input id="warrior-27" type="radio" name="warrior" value="27">
    <label for="warrior-27">makapaka</label>
    <input id="warrior-29" type="radio" name="warrior" value="29">
    <label for="warrior-29">Kasia</label>
</div>
```

What should i need to do. I tried search from web but i have still nothing from 2 days :(

Comment: Does [this blog article](http://www.ideacode.com/content/plug-in-custom-Zend-Form-decorators) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current option does not allow rendering in the exact format you wished.

It can only be either

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="warrior-27">
        <input type="radio" name="warrior" id="warrior-27" value="27">makapaka</label>
    <label for="warrior-29">
        <input type="radio" name="warrior" id="warrior-29" value="29">Kasia</label>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="warrior-27">
        makapaka
        <input type="radio" name="warrior" id="warrior-27" value="27"></label>
    <label for="warrior-29">
        Kasia
        <input type="radio" name="warrior" id="warrior-29" value="29"></label>
</div>
```

To render your form element as you mentioned, you need to create either a custom view helper and pass it as an option to the `ViewHelper` decorator or use the `ViewScript` decorator to generate a custom output.

Personally, I would prefer the `ViewScript` decorator for its easy of use.

Example of use :

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'warrior',array(
        'decorators' => array(
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'decorator.phtml'))
        )
    ));
```

and in your **decorator.phtml**

```
<div class="radio">
    <?php foreach($this->element->getMultiOptions() as $value => $label): ?>
    <input id="<?php echo $this->element->getName() ?>-<?php echo $value ?>" type="radio" name="<?php echo $this->element->getName() ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $this->element->getName() ?>-<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $label ?></label>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

**NB** : This script file can be used for all your form radio elements

Hope it helps

Comment: I changed my FormArena on viewScript and added decorator.phtm to view/script but now i have error: Plugin by name 'Decorator.phtml' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Form_Decorator_

Comment: @user3602115 : Sorry, I fixed that line. Check again